# Associative array returning first character of string

Tags: php

I have 3 classes: `server`, `client`, `service`. used to implement a SOAP web service.

The `service` constructs an associative array, then passes it to the `client` which finally passes it to the `server`. And a response is sent back.

Relevant code:

`service.php`

```
<?php
include './client.php';

$id_array = array("country_code"=> "+36");
echo $client->getName($id_array);
?>
```

`client.php`

```
public function getName($id_array)
{
    return $this->instance->__soapCall('getCountryName', $id_array);
}
```

and `server.php`

```
public function getCountryName($id_array)
    {
    $country_code = array();

    $country_code = $id_array['country_code'];
//this return value to debug (not actual function)
    return $country_code;
}
```

The problem occurs at: `$country_code = $id_array['country_code'];`
At which point `$country_code` is given the value `+`, instead of `+36`.

Why is that happening?

P.S. __soapCall passes the `$id_array` to the function `getCountryName()` in `server.php`
Also, everything works as intended if I use `$country_code` of length 1.

Comment: Without the code for `__soapCall()` there is no way to see what happens to `$id_array`. The rest of the code does not do anything wrong with it.

Comment: @DennisB. http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a SOAP user, but I believe `__soapCall('getCountryName', $id_array)` should be `__soapCall('getCountryName', array($id_array))`.

Why? Because each array index gets mapped to a param in the server method that gets called.

So, I think that in the server method, `$id_array`'s value is the first character of the country code string, if you added an `$id_array2` in the method param list, it would probably be the second in the string.

If that's the case, you're probably surpressing notices / warnings (check your errors logs) complaining about an illegal offset.

Comment: @Airwavezx You can thank him by upvoting and accept his answer .